# P2 profile doesn't include bundles installed via p2 Operations API

Tags: installation, equinox, p2

We have an Eclipse product with already implemented update mechanism of 'Checking for Available Updates' on startup using standard p2 Operations API or 'p2 Silent Update'. This works perfectly fine, Update operation can resolve all the dependencies, like which updates are installed and which are not, and if new updates are available it will download them correctly.

I have implemented a similar functionality of 'Check for Available New Installs' on startup using the same Operations API or 'p2 Silent install'. My code looks the following:

```
InstallOperation install = new InstallOperation(provisioningSession, toInstall); 
IStatus status = install.resolveModal(null);
if (status.getSeverity() == IStatus.OK) {
    Job job = operation.getProvisioningJob(null);
    job.schedule();
}
```

The problem is that after I install new bundles (only visible after restart of the application), I need to check that they are already installed, I use the standard API for that:

```
IProfileRegistry profileRegistry = (IProfileRegistry) provisioningAgent.getService(IProfileRegistry.SERVICE_NAME);
IProfile profile = profileRegistry.getProfile(IProfileRegistry.SELF);
Collection<IInstallableUnit> alreadyInstalled = profile.available(QueryUtil.ALL_UNITS, null).toUnmodifiableSet();
```

The problem is that the list of installed units doesn't include my newly installed bundles. Another strange observation that my application would try to install the same bundles all the time because InstallOperation resolves to OK as if those bundles were never installed (I assume that is because they are not actually included in the current p2 profile, same result as I get when listing all installed bundles from the current profile, see code above).

I would like to know if that is a bug or there is another separate p2 profile which includes the bundles installed via Operations API, and why they do not get registered as part of current profile (even though I can see they are copied and installed in my app correctly).

The Operations API:

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_api_overview.htm